# Set height equal to browser height

Tags: html, css

We are facing a height issue. We want to make page height 100% of browser view, but if set height to 100% then a scroll bar is there.

If set height of section around 90%, the scroll bar hides in some screen but not in all. There is fixed height of the header (`50px`). Is there any way to get the exact percentage for section depending on browser height?

```css
html,body {margin:0;height:100%;width:100%;}

header {
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  color:#fff;
}
section {
  height:100%;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<section></section>
```

Comment: Include the minimal required code to reproduce the issue in Question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `overflow:hidden;` on the `body`, or you can use `calc` instead:

```
height:calc(100% - [height of navbar]);`
```

So your css:

```
#content {
    height:calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

```css
html,body {margin:0;height:100%;width:100%;}
header {
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  color:#fff;
}
section {
  height:calc(100% - 50px);
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<section></section>
```

```css
html,body {margin:0;height:100%;width:100%;overflow:hidden;}
header {
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  color:#fff;
}
section {
  height:100%;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<section></section>
```

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

```
.my-div{
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: That will remove your top margin i guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can try putting

**body
{
 height:100vh;
}**

the height will be 100% height of the screen(viewport).

 Can u provide **jsfiddle** link if its still not working??

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this you can use `overflow: hidden`

```
<body style"height:100%; overflow:hidden;">
```

Hope it will help.